# Printing JSON formatted like Facebook does

Tags: php, json

Here the example: https://graph.facebook.com/19292868552

How is it possible? The source of the page is just as the page appears! There's no code of any kind. If you try to change the last 2 number in the url you can get other examples.
How do they print this JSON with carriage return after every element of the array without any sort of `<br/>`?
In php.net I can't find any way to nicely print JSON like this.

```
 $vettore = array(
    "uno" => 1,
    "due" => 2,
    "tre" => 3
 );

 header("Content-Type: text/javascript; charset=UTF-8");
 echo json_encode($vettore, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the reply headers, there's this line:

```
Content-Type: text/javascript; charset=UTF-8
```

By this the browser knows that the page is not HTML and doesn't try to format it as such.

Answer (score 1):

Tell the browser that it's plain text, then just pretty print it.

```
header('Content-type: text/plain');
```

Although they actually use `text/javascript`, as shown by the page properties.

Comment: How do I pretty print it then? The pretty print constant doesn't seem to be valid, it throws me a warning about an undefined constant!

Comment: Are you using PHP 5.3.0 or higher?

Comment: [hysoka@localhost ~]$ php --version
PHP 5.3.6 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Jun 15 2011 08:27:41) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2011 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2011 Zend Technologies

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this, it doesn't seem the best way to achieve neatly formatted Json but it does work.

```
$json_stuff = array(
   "url"         => "http://example.com",
   "name"        => "my name",
   "description" => "some description",
   "other"       => "some text"
);

foreach ($json_stuff as $key => $val) {
   $json_string .= "\"${key}\" : \"${val}\",\n";
}

header('Content-Type: application/json');
die("{\n".rtrim($json_string, ",\n")."\n}");
```

Above would output below with line breaks and without backslashs in urls.

```
{
"url" : "http://example.com",
"name" : "my name",
"description" : "some description",
"other" : "some text"
}
```